# React slider does not transitioning - styled components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I'm struggling with slider transition in React and styled components.

So slider itself is working but there's no transition between slides, just like another frame in a movie.

There's a slider itself:

```js
const Slider = () => {
    const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0)
    const handleClick = (e, direction) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(slideIndex);
        if (direction === "left") {
          setSlideIndex(slideIndex > 0 ? slideIndex - 1 : sliderItems.length - 1);
        } else {
          setSlideIndex(slideIndex < sliderItems.length - 1 ? slideIndex + 1 : 0);
        }}
  return (
    <Container>
         <Arrow direction="left" onClick={(e)=>handleClick(e,"left")}>
            <ArrowLeftSharp />
        </Arrow>
        <Wrapper>
            <Slide key={sliderItems[slideIndex].id}>
                <ImgContainer>
                    <Image src={sliderItems[slideIndex].img} />
                </ImgContainer>
                <InfoContainer>
                <Title>{sliderItems[slideIndex].title}</Title>
                <Description>{sliderItems[slideIndex].description}</Description>
                <Button>{sliderItems[slideIndex].buttonText}</Button>
                </InfoContainer>
            </Slide>
        </Wrapper>
        <Arrow direction="right" onClick={(e)=>handleClick(e,"right")}>
            <ArrowRightSharp />
        </Arrow>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

and here's wrapper styled component:

```js
const Wrapper = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transform: translateX(${props=> props.slideIndex * -100}vw);
`;
```

Does anyone has any idea why the transition not working? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't pass any props to Wrapper component
2. You have only one slide not multiple slides

Comment: To the 2nd point - it was working this way, so after adding props to the wrapper is working as it should. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the `slideIndex` prop to the `Wrapper` component, try this:

```
const Slider = () => {
    const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex] = useState(0)
    const handleClick = (e, direction) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(slideIndex);
        if (direction === "left") {
          setSlideIndex(slideIndex > 0 ? slideIndex - 1 : sliderItems.length - 1);
        } else {
          setSlideIndex(slideIndex < sliderItems.length - 1 ? slideIndex + 1 : 0);
        }}
  return (
    <Container>
         <Arrow direction="left" onClick={(e)=>handleClick(e,"left")}>
            <ArrowLeftSharp />
        </Arrow>
        <Wrapper slideIndex={slideIndex}>
            <Slide key={sliderItems[slideIndex].id}>
                <ImgContainer>
                    <Image src={sliderItems[slideIndex].img} />
                </ImgContainer>
                <InfoContainer>
                <Title>{sliderItems[slideIndex].title}</Title>
                <Description>{sliderItems[slideIndex].description}</Description>
                <Button>{sliderItems[slideIndex].buttonText}</Button>
                </InfoContainer>
            </Slide>
        </Wrapper>
        <Arrow direction="right" onClick={(e)=>handleClick(e,"right")}>
            <ArrowRightSharp />
        </Arrow>
    </Container>
  )
}
```